# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm receiving this error when I run my application.

The error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:574)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366) 
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2031) 
            at com.example.syafiq.facialrecognition.Recognize_Face.onCreate(Recognize_Face.java:152)
```

The Recognize_Face.java:152) was pointed here:

```
(line 148) protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    (line 149) Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    (line 150) 1super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    (line 151) getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    (line 152) setContentView(R.layout.activity_recognize__face);
```

my activity_recognize_face.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e7bc3a">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.88"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.88">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCat"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:text="@string/SViewAll"
            android:background="#4892f4"/>

            <com.example.syafiq.facialrecognition.Tutorial3View
                android:id="@+id/tutorial3_activity_java_surface_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.88" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lightbulb" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewState"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SIdle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_green" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_yellow" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_red" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.07"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@string/STrain"
            android:textOff="@string/STrain"
            android:textOn="@string/SStopTrain"
            android:background="#4892f4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.71"
            android:text="@string/SFaceName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.76"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonBuscar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/SSearch"
            android:textOff="@string/SSearch"
            android:textOn="@string/SStopSearch"
            android:background="#4892f4" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButtonGrabar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Grabar"
            android:textOff="Rec"
            android:textOn="Stop"
            android:background="#4892f4" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.73"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_camera" />

       </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me :/ I'm really appreciate your time and help for consideration for solving my error. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have a custom view referenced in your layout XML, and the custom view doesn't have the required `public` constructor that takes in `Context,AttributeSet` arguments.

Comment: Hi laalto :) I couldn't understand what do you meant, I'm new to android development I'm sorry :/ but I've included my xml files :D

Comment: In your code, `Tutorial3View` does not have the 2-arg constructor `Tutorial3View(Context, AttributeSet)` that is required for layout inflation.

Comment: Remember that those constructors have to be public.

Comment: @David you had me at `public`. Thanks much!

Comment: My app crash only in release build. The culprit is missing public.

Answer (score 108):

If you arrived at this post but are using **Kotlin**, annotate your constructor with `@JvmOverloads`.

Doc: [Kotlin - Overloads Generation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation)

```kotlin
class MyView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, 
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle)
```

Comment: FYI: this often results in unexpected side effects. i.e. for `AppCompatTextView` you have to remember to use `android.R.attr.textViewStyle` as the default value (instead of 0). Otherwise that's an easy way to introduce unwanted side effects to app behavior.

In most cases you only care about the two-argument constructor which is used when inflating from xml files

Comment: In my case I forgot to add  `= 0` to `defStyle: Int = 0`. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: In my case in addition there was an insufficient operator `constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)`.

Answer (score 4):

An improvement to @Shazbot's answer for Kotlin. Add these constructors:

```kotlin
class CustomView : View {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

}
```

When you need `init`:

```kotlin
class CustomView : View {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(null, 0)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(attrs, 0)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        init(attrs, defStyle)
    }

    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        // do something
    }
```